# Error in accessing API data in child component in React TanStack v8

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-table, tanstack

I am using TanStack v8 to represent tabular data. Below is my app(HomePage) structure. On HomePage, I am fetching data from API using useEffect and passing it to EmailTable.

```
<Header />
<Statistics />
{emails.length > 0 ? (
  <EmailTable
    emails={emails}
    isLoading={isLoading}
  />
  ) : (
  <Spinner />
)}
```

In EmailTable component, I am able to access/log the emails(api data). But, when I am passing that emails to useReactTable, I am getting multiple errors like **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**.
If I am storing emails data to some different variable and passing that variable to useReactTable, it is working fine.

[image: EmailTable component]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the type of function parameters does not match.
The `emails` is not in the options of `useReactTable` function parameter.
The options of the `useReactTable` function parameter can be found [here](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table#options).

Comment: Thanks for saving my time man. I thought we can pass any variable. Thanks alot.